# Как замокать URL Adress

Tags: c#, nunit

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, в ходе изучения библиотеки Wiremock, а именно локально получается запустить сервер и замокать его. А вот как добавить какой то другой URL и замокать не выходит.

```
namespace NUnitTestWiremock
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        WireMockServer server = WireMockServer.Start();
        string _mockURL;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            server.Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/test")
                .UsingGet())
                .RespondWith(Response.Create()
                .WithBodyAsJson("WireMock responce.")
                .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK));
            _mockURL = server.Urls[0] + "/test";
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestStatusCode()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_mockURL);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            server.Stop();
            server.Dispose();
        }
```

Каким образом сюда или не сюда передать необходимы для мока URL

```
WireMockServer server = WireMockServer.Start();
```

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` устарел и не рекомендуется для новой разработки (см. документацию по классу). Используйте `HttpClient`, его легко можно замокать просто подменив ему `HttpMessageHandler` на свой класс. Можно будет видеть все свои HTTP запросы и даже слать HTTP ответы при необходимости вообще не используя сеть, хотя приложение будет уверено что отвечает именно сервер.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но не совсем понимаю, если можете скинуть пару строк кода, было бы круто. И я правильно понял что это будет нормально работать с wiremock библиотекой ? Или нужно использовать moq ?

Comment: В методе `Setup` делается именно то, что вам нужно: указывается путь (url) и указывается ответ. / В конце концов, смотрите [документацию](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Using-WireMock-in-UnitTests).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я правильно понимаю что путь к Url указывается тут:  server.Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/test"). Посмотрел еще раз документацию и по моему я хочу получить лишнее от этой бибилиотеки. Еще хотел уточнить в Вас, правильно ли я понял что мы пытаемся заглушить какой то адрес, и для этого нам достаточно локально предоставленного URl? По факту ведь все нужные запросы будут стучать туда и получать ответы которые бы давал ннеобходимый нам сервис, а использование реальных URl из сети необязательно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь, удалось разобраться!